# Getting canvas path from div outline or border

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to create  a poker table with dots around the table to represent players. The image you can see below represents what I have done already and gives the general idea of what I want but, as you can see the dots (players) are not distributed equally. Is it possible to get the path value along the outer part of the table below and then iterate the 'chips' along it?

```
export default function PokerTable() {
    return (
        <div className='poker-table'>
            {
                [...Array(10)].map((index, key) =>(
                    <div className='player' key={key}>

                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
.poker-table {
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: #4aad4a;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 150px;
    position: relative;
    border: 15px solid #C0C0C0;

    &:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
        left: -15px;
    }
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 130px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}

.player{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 3px solid black;

    &:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        background-color: red;

    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
         top: 15%;
         left: 95%;
         background-color: yellow;
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
        top: 50%;
        left: 100%;
        background-color: green;
    }

     &:nth-child(4) {
        top: 85%;
        left: 95%;
        background-color: rgb(38, 0, 128);
    }

    &:nth-child(5) {
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        background-color: rgb(128, 0, 100);
    }

    &:nth-child(6) {
        top: 85%;
        left: 5%;
        background-color: rgb(90, 128, 0);
    }

     &:nth-child(7) {
        top: 50%;
        left: -2%;
        background-color: rgb(0, 128, 122);
    }

    &:nth-child(8) {
        top: 15%;
        left: 5%;
        background-color: rgb(26, 26, 10);
    }

    &:nth-child(9) {
        top: 4%;
        left: 22%;
        background-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);
    }

    &:nth-child(10) {
       top: 97%;
       left: 75%;
        background-color: rgb(106, 76, 179);
    }
}
```

[image: Poker table Image]

Comment: Are you looking for a responsive layout (i.e. same shape as you show above regardless of viewport aspect ratio/dimensions)?

Comment: yes that would work

Comment: At the moment your table shape will change depending on the aspect ratio of your viewport (as the table dimensions are defined in %s of width/height of viewport or any container) and the curvature is defined in absolute (px) units so that adds another parameter. On what screen size are you getting the shape you want?

Answer (score 1):

This answer takes a step back to consider a basic problem which has not been mentioned in the question.

There are problems if the table shape is defined in terms of percentage width and height of the viewport.

On different devices the table with have different aspect ratios. This could be overcome by always placing the table inside a container with fixed aspect ratio.

However, even then the table will look different on different container/viewport widths because the border radius has been defined in absolute (px) terms.

Basically, to have a consistent table shape you cannot mix relative and absolute units

This snippet defines the table purely in terms of its width, which in this example is set at 40vmin (if you use vmin you know it will always fit in the viewport). Everything else is calculated in relation to that using CSS variables and its calc function.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.poker-table {
    --w: 40vmin;
    --h: calc(var(--w) * 60 / 40);
    width: var(--w);
    height: var(--h);
    background-color: #4aad4a;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    --br: calc(var(--w) / 2); /* border radius */
    border-radius: var(--br);
    position: relative;
    --bw: calc(var(--w) / 20); /* border (the gray bit) width */
    border: var(--bw) solid #C0C0C0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='poker-table'>                   
</div>
```

Now to find the left and top positions (in CSS) terms where the player must be placed to ensure they are equally spaced around the table we need to do a bit of geometry.

In the above snippet the radius of the top and bottom of the table was chosen deliberately to make the calculation a bit easier. The border radius was defined as half the table width. So the parts of a circle which CSS uses to know where to paint are like in this picture:

[image]

And the entire length of the edge of the table is `2*PI*br + (2*h-2*br)` - the circumference of the circle (i.e. the 4 arcs in the corners) plus what remains of the height twice (the two straight edges).

The players need to be spaced around so the distance between them is one tenth of this length.

It's now a question of doing a bit of math to calculate the angle sub-tended by the second player, for example, and hence its left and top coordinates, then move onto the second player. Let me know if you need help with this - but it's stopped being HTML/CSS and gone on to be geometry!